# reading a binary unknown size file in c#

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, binaryfiles, huffman-code

I have just switched to c# from c++. I have already done some task in c++ and the same now i have to translate in c#.

I am going through some problems.

I have to find the frequency of symbols in binary files (which is taken as sole argument, so don't know it's size/length).(these frequency will be further used to create `huffman tree`).

**My code to do that in c++ is below :**

My structure is like this:

```
struct Node     
{    
    unsigned int symbol;
    int freq;    
    struct Node * next,  * left, * right;  
};
Node * tree;
```

And how i read the file is like this :

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(argv, "rb");
ch = fgetc(fp);

while (fread( & ch, sizeof(ch), 1, fp)) {
    create_frequency(ch);
}

fclose(fp);
```

**Could any one please help me in translating the same in c# (specially this binary file read procedure to create frequency of symbols and storing in linked list)?** Thanks for the help

Edit: Tried to write the code according to what Henk Holterman explained below but still there is error and the error is :

```
error CS1501: No overload for method 'Open' takes '1' arguments
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
shekhar_c#.cs(22,32): error CS0825: The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

And my code to do this is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // using provides exception-safe closing
    using (var fp = System.IO.File.Open(args))
    {
        int b; // note: not a byte
        while ((b = fp.Readbyte()) >= 0)
        {
            byte ch = (byte) b;
            // now use the byte in 'ch'
            //create_frequency(ch);
        }
    }
 }
```

And the line corresponding to the two errors is :

```
using (var fp = System.IO.File.Open(args))
```

could some one please help me ? I am beginner to c#

Comment: OK, my mistake(s). Try `fp = System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[1])`

Comment: @HenkHolterman error CS1061: Type `System.IO.FileStream' does not contain a definition for `Readbyte' and no extension method `Readbyte' of type `System.IO.FileStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The function is `ReadByte`, not `Readbyte`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string fileName = ...
using (var fp = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)) // using provides exception-safe closing
{
    int b; // note: not a byte

    while ((b = fp.ReadByte()) >= 0)
    {
        byte ch = (byte) b;
        // now use the byte in 'ch'
        create_frequency(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but in c++ code i had used "argv" which is taken from main and is like this "int main(int argc, char ** argv)" . I mean it has double pointers but we cant use * in c# . so how this argv work in c# ? and second question do i have to pass this "ch" in my create_freq()function to create node?

Comment: For me as a C# programmer, could you please explain why you use an `int b` (and even comment "not a byte")? And why do you comment `node: not a byte` without explaining why?

Comment: @user234839 - You were not to specific about where the filename comes from, C++'s `argv[1]` would be `args[0]` in C#. As long as it's a string.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - it's funny but the method named ReadByte() actually  returns an `int`. So that the special value `-1` can be used for EOF. This answer gives the basic pattern to deal with that encoding.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks! I never noticed that, as I never used `ReadByte` in real life. I rather use `Read` to read an entire buffer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman argv[1] means in c++ i was doing at termoanl like this "./filename Input_file.bin" so argv[0] is the command "./filename" and arggv[1] is "Input_file.bin" the name of bianry file whose frequency of the symbols is to be calculated.Now could you please explain that how to achieve this in c# ? how to go to the second argument of the termainal which is the name of binary file? Because i think argv[0] will point to the "mono" if i execute it at terminal like this "mono filename.cs  Input_Binary_file.bin".even i am reading the "binary file a 3rd position", so must be argv[2] ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have edited my code to explain more. please see the below part of my code, which contains the edit.